# Boostrap Form Radio Buttons are not the same length

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I am trying to create a quiz, but I am having issues with bootstrap 4.

I am trying to make the options (Panthers, Fighting Irish, Bears, Tigers) all the same length.

I have tried add col-sm-8 on all the classes with no luck. I have tried to target the classes with no luck.

Can someone point out what I am doing wrong.

Thanks,

```css
a {
  color: white;
  list-style: none;
 }
 a:visited {
   color:white;
   }
 
 body{
   font-family: arial;
   font-size: 15px;
   line-height: 1.6em;
   background: rgb(202, 202, 202);
 }
 
 li {
   list-style: none;
 }
 
 .container{
   width: 70%;
   margin: 20px auto;
   overflow: auto;
 }
 
 .pull-left{float:left;}
 .pull-right{float:right;}
 
 header {
   background: blue;
   color: white;
   padding: 5px 10px;
   overflow: auto;
   font-size: 16px;
 }
 
 
 footer {
     background: blue;
     color: white;
     padding: 5px 10px;
     overflow: auto;
     font-size: 15px;
   }
 
.optionName{
}

.optionText{

}

 @media only screen and (max-width: 900px) {
   .container{
     width: 90%;
   }
   }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <title>College Football Quiz</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>

</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="pull-left"><a href="index.html">College Mascot Quiz</a></div>
            <div class="pull-right">by Rob Connoly</div>
        </header>


        <div class="main">

            <form class="questionForm" id="question1" data-question="1">
                <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Question 1</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">University of Notre Dame.</p>
                        <div class="input-group">

                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <label> <input class="optionName" name="question1" type="radio" aria-label="Panthers" value=
                                        'a'>  Panthers  
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text col-xs-6">
                                    <label> <input class="col-xs-3 optionName" name="question1" type="radio" aria-label="FightingIrish" value="b">  Fighting Irish  
                                    </label>  
                                </div>
                            </div>


                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text col-xs-6 ">
                                    <label> <input class="optionName" name="question1" type="radio" aria-label="bears" value="c">  Bears  
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>

                            <div class="col-xs-6 input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text col-xs-6">
                                    <label> <input class="optionName" name="question1" type="radio" aria-label="Tigers" value="d">  Tigers  
                                    </label>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>

                <!-- <h3>1. University of Notre Dame</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question1" value="a" /> Panthers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question1" value="b" /> Fighting Irish </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question1" value="c" /> Bears </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question1" value="d" /> Tigers </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form> -->

            <!-- <form class="questionForm" id="question2" data-question="2">
                <h3>2. University of Southern California</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question2" value="a" /> Trojans </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question2" value="b" /> Aztecs </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question2" value="c" /> Bobcats </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question2" value="d" /> Boomer </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>

            <form class="questionForm" id="question3" data-question="3">
                <h3>3. University of California</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question3" value="a" /> Prowlers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question3" value="b" /> Scarlets </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question3" value="c" /> Golden Bears </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question3" value="d" /> Ducks </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>

            <form class="questionForm" id="question4" data-question="4">
                <h3>4. Clemson University</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question4" value="a" /> Zippy </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question4" value="b" /> Hokies </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question4" value="c" /> Rebels </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question4" value="d" /> Tigers </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>

            <form class="questionForm" id="question5" data-question="5">
                <h3>5. University of New Mexico</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question5" value="a" /> Cavaliers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question5" value="b" /> Lobos </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question5" value="c" /> Gamecocks </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question5" value="d" /> Devils </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>

            <form class="questionForm" id="question6" data-question="6">
                <h3>6. University of Nebraska</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question6" value="a" /> Gophers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question6" value="b" /> Fighting Hawks </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question6" value="c" /> Comets </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question6" value="d" /> Cornhuskers </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>

            <form class="questionForm" id="question7" data-question="7">
                <h3>7. Austin Peay University</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question7" value="a" /> Highlanders </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question7" value="b" /> Governors </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question7" value="c" /> Jets </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question7" value="d" /> Lynx </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>


            <form class="questionForm" id="question8" data-question="8">
                <h3>8. Stanford University</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question8" value="a" /> Captians </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question8" value="b" /> Cardinals </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question8" value="c" /> Gladiators </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question8" value="d" /> Hillcats </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>


            <form class="questionForm" id="question9" data-question="9">
                <h3>9. University of Indiana</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question9" value="a" /> Horned Frogs </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question9" value="b" /> Engineers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question9" value="c" /> Coyotes </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question9" value="d" /> Hoosiers </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>


            <form class="questionForm" id="question10" data-question="10">
                <h3>10. University of Georgetown</h3>
                <ul>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question10" value="a" /> Gold Diggers </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question10" value="b" /> Knights </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question10" value="c" /> Ice Dogs </li>
                    <li><input type="radio" name="question10" value="d" /> Hoyas </li>
                </ul>
                <button id='submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>





 -->

            <div id="results"></div>
            <br>

            <footer>
                <div class="pull-left">
                    Total: 10 Questions
                </div>
                <div id="stopWatch" class="pull-right">
                    0
                </div>
            </footer>

        </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should check [this](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/input-group/#checkboxes-and-radios) link

You can make the fields readonly, which will disable the actual input.

**Example:**

```
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button"
                                placeholder="Panthers" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button"
                                placeholder="Fighting Irish" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button"
                                placeholder="Bears" readonly>
                        </div>
                        <div class="input-group">
                            <div class="input-group-prepend">
                                <div class="input-group-text">
                                    <input type="radio" aria-label="Radio button for following text input">
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with radio button"
                                placeholder="Tigers" readonly>
                        </div>
```

Or you can check the forms documentation - [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/forms/#checkboxes-and-radios)

With an example:

```
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios1"
                            value="option1" checked>
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios1">
                            Panthers
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios2"
                            value="option2">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios2">
                            Fighting Irish
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios3"
                            value="option2">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios3">
                            Bears
                        </label>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-check">
                        <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="exampleRadios" id="exampleRadios4"
                            value="option2">
                        <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleRadios4">
                            Tigers
                        </label>
                    </div>
```